# Installing mysql2 gem - HAVE_UINT (ushort, uint type redefinition errors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, mysql2

Yes, this is yet another question about installing the mysql2 gem for use in Ruby on Rails.  But it's an error I haven't been able to find listed in another question.

I've got the 64 bit MySQL and RVM installed on OS X Mountain Lion.  When trying to install the mysql2 gem, I keep getting an error from `make` about redefinition of `ushort` and `uint` in mysql2_ext.h.  I found that file in a couple of different places (apparently cached, because changing the file did nothing when I reran the `gem install mysql2` command) and found these lines in it:

```
#ifndef HAVE_UINT
#define HAVE_UINT
typedef unsigned short    ushort;
typedef unsigned int    uint;
#endif
```

It is indeed trying to redefine `ushort` and `uint` even though it still has them.  How do I tell it that the symbols are already defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's a way to specify your CFLAGS to force it to recognize the HAVE_UINT definition.  It is NOT this (apparently the gem installation manages to ignore environment variables set this way):

> sudo env CFLAGS="-DHAVE_UINT" gem install mysql2

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761670/is-there-any-way-to-change-gcc-compilation-options-for-a-gem) for how to do this:

> gem install mysql2 -- --with-cflags=\"-DHAVE_UINT\"

And it worked!