# Installation -- mysql2 gem fails on OSX Mavericks using rbenv and Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, mysql2, rbenv

I somehow managed to install Ruby 1.8.7 using rbenv on OSX Mavericks (which ships with Ruby 2.0) after countless tries.

However I'm getting an error when installing mysql2 that is very difficult for me to understand. Can somebody point me into a direction to resolve this?
Please see the output below:

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p370/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for rb_hash_dup()... no
checking for rb_intern3()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 -I. -I. -I/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p370/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin13.0.0 -I. -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H -I'/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p370/include' -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE  -I'/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p370/include' -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64 -fno-common -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe -fno-common  -Wall -funroll-loops  -c client.c
In file included from client.c:1:
./mysql2_ext.h:13: error: redefinition of typedef ‘ushort’
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:91: error: previous declaration of ‘ushort’ was here
./mysql2_ext.h:14: error: redefinition of typedef ‘uint’
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:92: error: previous declaration of ‘uint’ was here
client.c: In function ‘set_charset_name’:
client.c:1045: warning: unused variable ‘mysql2rb’
make: *** [client.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p370/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p370/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Just now I found this which worked fine:

gem install mysql2 -- --with-cflags=\"-DHAVE_UINT\"

Source: [Installing mysql2 gem - HAVE_UINT (ushort, uint type redefinition errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888780/installing-mysql2-gem-have-uint-ushort-uint-type-redefinition-errors)