# ruby compile with fPIC

Tags: ruby, qt, rbenv

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p392 through rbenv under Debian 7 and I'm trying to install the qtbindings gem so I can run an old ruby app which uses qt libs.

Here is the error I get when typing 'gem install qtbindings'

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/ext/build'
[ 82%] Building CXX object ruby/qtruby/src/CMakeFiles/qtruby4shared.dir/Qt.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object ruby/qtruby/src/CMakeFiles/qtruby4shared.dir/handlers.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object ruby/qtruby/src/CMakeFiles/qtruby4shared.dir/marshall_types.o
Linking CXX shared library libqtruby4shared.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/libruby-static.a(array.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/libruby-static.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [ruby/qtruby/src/libqtruby4shared.so.2.0.0] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/ext/build'
make[2]: *** [ruby/qtruby/src/CMakeFiles/qtruby4shared.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/ext/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/ext/build'
make: *** [build] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0/./gem_make.out
```

I've installed the following requirements

```
sudo aptitude install cmake build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev vim libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libreadline5-dev libreadline6-dev libxml2-dev git-core subversion autoconf xorg-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev qtcreator
```

How do I compile ruby with fPIC?
I've also tried 'gem install qtbindings -- -fPIC' but got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
#gem install qtbindings -- --with-cflags=\"-fPIC\"
```

Source:
[Is there any way to change gcc compilation options for a gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761670/is-there-any-way-to-change-gcc-compilation-options-for-a-gem)

**Edited:**

Yeah, gave another look to your code, my fault. The problem is with the installed ruby, not with the gem.

Look at [this](https://github.com/Groogy/rbSFML/issues/53) (Last post)

Try reinstalling ruby with shared libraries:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" rbenv install 1.9.3-p392
```

Comment: I still get the same problem when running this.

Comment: Was running into this trying to get my kids set up with KidsRuby. Your answer looks like its going to save my bacon. Thanks a lot.