# Bundler install with cflags / distcc for a Rails 4 appllication

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, distcc, cflags

I am setting up a Rails 4 application on a Raspberry Pi.  In order to speed up the installation of gems when I run bundle install I set up a distcc server (with the ARM cross compiler) on my Linux desktop.

What I cannot find is a way to pass either via CFLAGS or some other means the command to use distcc when I run 'bundle install'.  Bundler does not recognise the --with-cflags switch.

In searching for a solution I have found how to do this on a gem by gem basis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761670/is-there-any-way-to-change-gcc-compilation-options-for-a-gem) but I would prefer a setup where it could all be done with one command.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This may be an issue caused by my using RVM.  In which case, other than not using RVM it looks like there is not much I can do.  https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1600